# What is the ngCookies (AngularJS) in Angular 4 or 5

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, cookies

what's the $cookies on AngularJS in Angular 4/5?

for example in AngularJS

```
let app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
app.controller('MainController', MainController);
MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$cookies'];
function MainController($scope, $cookies){
  $cookies.put('msg', 'Hello World');
  $scope.msgFromCookie= $cookies.get('msg');
}
```

Comment: Is [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) what you're looking for?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

Comment: @cyberpirate92 if it can store object data, yes

Comment: @SurajKhanal Can I use angular2-cookie to my angular 5 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several npm packages that you can use for handling cookies in Angular4/5.
Such as 'ngx-cookie-service, you can get it with npm

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service --save
```

You add the cookie service to your module as a provider (As you would with any service), then inject it into a component and use it.

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) { }

this.cookieService.set('msg', 'Hello World');
this.cookieService.get('msg');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)**

1. Add the cookie service to your app.module.ts as a provider:

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

   @NgModule({
       declarations: [AppComponent],
       imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
       providers: [CookieService],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
2. Then, import and inject it into a component:

   ```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
   ```

   Referance : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service